# Gradient overlay on image in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, overlay, gradient, transparent

I have an image that is mostly transparent. I would like to be able to overlay a gradient on top of it but only have it visible over the non transparent areas.

Is there any way to do this outside of drawing a path on top of it and filling that?

Answer (score 1):

Why not swap the transparent and opaque areas and but the image above the gradient?

You could look into using a bitmap as an opacity mask

http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=100043